# Centring text over a button CSS

Tags: html, css

I am playing with CSS and buttons and I would like the text History to be over the centre of the button, but it appears at the top of the cell. How can I get it into the middle vertically?

[image]

CSS

```
a.button {
background: url(button.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width: 150px;
height: 62px;
display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<td  align="center" valign="middle" >
<a href="history.htm" class="button"/><b>HISTORY</b></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only one line text, than i usually use `line-height` = `height`

```css
a.button {
  background: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 62px;
  display: block;

  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="history.htm" class="button"/><b>HISTORY</b></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "Vertical-align:middle;" in you a.button css rule.